# parse log file using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Is there any easy way to parse machine generated log files?
Here is 1 line from the file that I am trying to read and save to SQL.

```
import re

mytext='''2018-07-22 08:12:02 Receive DR [SMAC:PI_ID_VOP3_N_K_T] [SVC:vikan2] [ACT:vitp3] [BINF:] [FID:e6f97a4b-c4bc-4aa1-876b-3a5ce40b4cfd] [META:?spp?dl_err=%03%00%
00&] [from:ALERTS] [to:91985] [flags:-1:-1:-1:-1:1] [msg:132:id:e6f97a4b-c4bc-4aa1-876b-3a5ce40b4cfd sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:180722070002 done date:1807220
81157 stat:DEL err:000 text:] [udh:0:] 
'''

values = re.search(r'SVC:(.*)]', mytext)
print (values.groups())
```

Intead of returning only '**vikan2**' it returns a long string...

> ('vikan2] [ACT:vitp3] [BINF:]
>   [FID:e6f97a4b-c4bc-4aa1-876b-3a5ce40b4cfd',)

I am trying to convert the string to dictionary that will look like this...

```
{'log_date':'2018-07-22 08:12:02', 'log_entry':'Receive DR',
     'SMAC': 'PI_ID_VOP3_N_K_T',
     'SVC': 'vikan2',
     'ACT': 'vitp3',
     'BINF': '',
     'FID': 'e6f97a4b-c4bc-4aa1-876b-3a5ce40b4cfd',
     'META': '?spp?dl_err=%03%00%\n00&',
     'from': 'ALERTS',
     'to': '91985',
     'flags': '-1:-1:-1:-1:1',
     'msg': '132:id:e6f97a4b-c4bc-4aa1-876b-3a5ce40b4cfd',
     'sub': '001',
     'dlvrd': '001',
     'submit date': '180722070002',
     'done date': '1807220\n81157',
     'stat': 'DEL',
     'err': '000',
     'text': '',
     'udh': '0:'}
```

---

Update:

1) I am not able to read the "meta" field (i.e. did not return expected string **'?spp?dl_err=%03%00%\n00&'**

2) I am able to build the dictinoary using this code. But I am sure there must better way to do this.

```
svc = re.search(r'SVC:(.*?)]', mytext)
smc = re.search(r'SMC:(.*?)]', mytext)
act = re.search(r'ACT:(.*?)]', mytext)
binf = re.search(r'BINF:(.*?)]', mytext)
fid = re.search(r'FID:(.*?)]', mytext)
from1 = re.search(r'from:(.*?)]', mytext)
to1 = re.search(r'to:(.*?)]', mytext)
flags = re.search(r'flags:(.*?)]', mytext)
msg = re.search(r'msg:(.*?)\s', mytext)
sub = re.search(r'sub:(.*?)\s', mytext)
dlvrd = re.search(r'dlvrd:(.*?)\s', mytext)
submit_date = re.search(r'submit date:(.*?)\s', mytext)
done_date = re.search(r'done date:(.*?)\s', mytext)
stat = re.search(r'stat:(.*?)\s', mytext)
err = re.search(r'err:(.*?)\s', mytext)
text = re.search(r'text:(.*?)]', mytext)
udh = re.search(r'udh:(.*?)]', mytext)

mydict=dict()

mydict['SVC'] = svc.groups()[0]
mydict['SMC'] = smc.groups()[0]
mydict['ACT'] = act.groups()[0]
mydict['BINF'] = binf.groups()[0]
mydict['FID'] = fid.groups()[0]
mydict['from'] = from1.groups()[0]
mydict['to'] = to1.groups()[0]
mydict['flags'] = flags.groups()[0]
mydict['msg'] = msg.groups()[0]
mydict['sub'] = sub.groups()[0]
mydict['dlvrd'] = dlvrd.groups()[0]
mydict['submit_date'] = submit_date.groups()[0]
mydict['done_date'] = done_date.groups()[0]
mydict['stat'] = stat.groups()[0]
mydict['err'] = err.groups()[0]
mydict['text'] = text.groups()[0]
mydict['udh'] = udh.groups()[0]
```

Comment: It's a matter of greediness. Do `SVC:(.*?)]`

Comment: Question got closed so I can't answer, but you might use `(?<=\[| )([A-Za-z ]+?):([^\s\]]+)` to get all matches at once rather than hard-coding every property name

Comment: @revo I have edited my question to be specific with 2 issues.

Comment: Try `\A(?P<log_date>\S+ +\S+) +(?P<log_entry>.*?(?= *\[))| +\[?([^:]+):([^] ]*)`. Please see [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/K8OzD0/1). You have `log_date` and `log_entry` in two separate groups and other pairs in 3rd and 4th capturing groups.

Comment: Yes. This worked. But can you post it as answer?